# iPhone: ViewController ends up badly after simulating memory warning

Tags: iphone

I have a view controller HomeViewController which shows some grids. Once I go to an inner view controller by clicking on a grid, I do a "Simulate memory warning" in the Simulator menu. Now, when I press back button go back to HomeViewController, the grids become bare - white in colour.

Any idea why this is happening ? Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Some more details: The HomeViewController view is itself loads from a NIB. Each of the grid (GridView) loads separately from a Grid.xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HomeViewController will unload its view when it receives a memory warning while its view is not visible. Make sure you reload everything `viewDidLoad` that gets unloaded when the view is released. Also, your views must not hold any state on their own; you must be able to reconstruct every view with the data you hold in your model and controller objects.